# A trigger to calculate hour difference between two DateTime fields

Tags: sqlite

3 fields in a Table : START_DATE, END_DATE , DIFF. All three are DATETIME fields. I would like a trigger (AFTER UPDATE) to calculate the time difference between the START_DATE and END_DATE values in the DIFF field. I would like the result to be like : 01 Day -  12 Hours - 15 Min. How can I achieve this ? I would like to know also how it is done i.e the way to show the hour difference so that DIFF would display something like 27:15:00.

This seems to work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DIFF]
AFTER UPDATE OF [end_date]
ON [Table1]
BEGIN
UPDATE Table1 SET DIFF = 
cast(
         (
                  strftime('%s',Table1.end_date)-strftime('%s',Table1.start_date)
         ) AS INT
      ) / 60/60 ;
END
```

Comment: How is this question related to Delphi?

Comment: What particular part of the documentation for [triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) and [date/time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) do you not understand?

Comment: You are mixing formatting with storage. A datetime field contain a timestamp. How you present the timestamp to the user is not relevant for the trigger.

Comment: @adrianm - I wish I could understand what you are talking about ? Do you mean to tell me that the DIFF field can be DateTime too?

Comment: Your question starts with `All three are DATETIME fields.` and then you talk about formatting

Comment: what is the solution then if the DIFF is datetime field? The above example does not work if the Diff is the datetime field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this works ok:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TIME_DIFFERENCE]
AFTER UPDATE OF [end_date]
ON [Table1]
BEGIN
UPDATE Table1 SET DIFF = 
cast(
         (
                  strftime('%s',Table1.end_date)-strftime('%s',Table1.start_date)
         ) AS INT
      ) / 60/60 ;
END
```